# ¿Como puedo agregar una coordenada en gmap pasandole como parametro un String?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

tengo un programa en c#, necesito analizar unos datos y mostrarlos en un mapa. El problema está que solo tengo información del Pais y ciudad pero no como coordenada si no en forma de texto. Mi pregunta es como puedo yo, pasarle un String por parametro al Gmap y que este me busque el sitio que le definí.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que a partir de un String sacar las coordenadas de esa dirección no?. PD: Si es posible agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento para darnos una idea de lo que tienes. PD2 : Puede que esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354867/how-to-find-latitude-and-longitude-using-c-sharp) de SO te sirva para algo(La segunda respuesta). Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Creo esto es lo que buscas
Usando el api de google. Primero debes de habilitar este metodo dentro de la consola de google.

```
requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0},{1}&result_type=street_address&key={2}", latitude, longitude, strKeyApiMaps);
```

Mandar la latitud, longitud y tu apikey habilitada.
Te regresa un objeto que debes de validar

```
                    resultContent = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    JObject objResult = JObject.Parse(resultContent);

                    if (objResult["status"].Value<string>().Equals("OK", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        strResult = objResult["results"][0]["formatted_address"].Value<string>();

                    }
                    else if (objResult["status"].Value<string>().Equals("ZERO_RESULTS", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        //Tu codigo si no obtiene resultados
                    }
```

Solamente recuerda que google ya te cuenta las peticiones al API y si abusas, te pedirá cambiar tu cuenta a un cuota mensual